# double sided induction motor?

Tags: induction-motor

Some background to what I'm actually trying to do:

I'm working on a project where I need a very smooth motion control at variable, and very low, speeds and I thought induction motors would be well suited for this task. However they seam to be rather expensive to buy compared to other motors so I thought I would try to build my own.

After some looking around some I came across double sided linear induction motors and I got curious if a regular rotor motor would see any benefit from being double sided too. Mainly because I don't want to deal with a squirrel cage, from my understanding they can cause the rotor to "lock up" in certain positions making it run less smooth, especially at very low speeds. So I figured if double sided linear induction motors are better than regular linear induction motors this has to be the case for rotary motors too, right? But I cannot even find a single page about double sided rotary motors.
Does anyone know why double sided induction motors is not a thing?

Also, if anyone has a better suggestion for motors with very smooth speed control I would be very interested to hear about it. It needs to basically be able to be variable down to 0, or "infinitely variable", though a very broad range would probably work too.

Comment: A link to the "double sided linear induction motors" that you came across might be helpful. There are wound rotor induction motors, but they are nearly extinct because electronically-controlled squirrel cage motors are generally better. Any motor will work better at extremely low speeds if it has a shaft speed and position encoder for feedback. A permanent magnet motor may be a better choice depending on the power level required. You are going to need specific maximum and minimum RPM objectives and a specific torque objective. You also need to quantify "very smooth."

Comment: You need to specify torque specs and some idea of speed. You effectively want position control. Microstepping with a stepper-motor or the equivalent with a brushless DC motor is needed. At super slow speeds an induction motor still needs a rotating field to induce the rotor flux. This is doable (search locked-rotor measurements) but may need magic level control. IF you search for VESC - Benjamin Vedder. While his work is mostly used at somewhat higher speeds it should be extensible to static situations, and the software is open source. ...

Comment: [VESC search](https://www.google.com/search?q=benjamin+vesc&rlz=1C1CHBF_enNZ834NZ839&oq=benjamin+vesc&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5j69i60.4775j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Cool, though I was mostly wondering why there was no double sided rotary induction motors, but that is a good resource you provided :)

Comment: @CharlesCowie Here's a link to a site with a double sided linear motor https://www.electrical4u.com/linear-induction-motor/ Also, regarding "how smooth", I need something like +-0.002 rpm, I was thinking of doing a direct drive system with a closed control loop.

Comment: Expensive to buy compared to what?  For applications between about 1/4 horsepower to huge, induction motors are pretty much ubiquitous, precisely because they are inexpensive.  You need to get more specific in what sort of speeds, torques, and precision you're contemplating.

Comment: I don't have a mental image of what a double sided ROTARY induction motor looks like. Usually you have an internal squirrel cage and external would stator. How are the "double sides" inter-related mechanically?

Comment: That double sided motor has the "primary" armature wound in two identical parts and a "cage" "secondary." That could be practicable for a rotating machine, but probably only for a slow-speed, large-diameter machine with a lot of poles. It could look something like a rotating-disc, kilowatt-hour meter.

Comment: @CharlesCowie That is exactly what I am looking to build, slow speed large diameter motor with lots of poles :P  Hence why I am interested in why I can't find any motors like this.

Comment: Search "pancake motor."

Comment: @CharlesCowie Thank you! These are the motors I am looking for! Who knew pancakes would be the thing to save me :P